# Using ngStorage can I use a var as the stored name/key?

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I'm just getting my feet wet with ngStorge so this is probably simple.

I'm using https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.

Here is their read/write demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>

    <script>
      angular.module('app', [
        'ngStorage'
      ]).

      controller('Ctrl', function(
        $scope,
        $localStorage
      ){
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
          x: 42
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="$storage.x = $storage.x + 1">{{$storage.x}}</button> + <button ng-click="$storage.y = $storage.y + 1">{{$storage.y}}</button> = {{$storage.x + $storage.y}}
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview

I want to use a var for the stored name/key.

So instead of:

```
<button ng-click="$storage.x = $storage.x + 1">{{$storage.x}}</button>
```

I would like to use:

```
var testx = 'x';
```

And use testx insted of .x

```
<button ng-click="$storage.x = $storage.x + 1">{{$storage.x}}</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you set the variable to the key value? Or is that not what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right you can use the brackets notation like in the code bellow:

```
<button ng-click="$storage[ testx ] = $storage[ testx ] + 1">{{$storage[ testx ]}}</button>
```